# What's the best tool to find and replace regular expressions over multiple files?

Tags: regex, search, replace

Preferably free tools if possible.

Also, the option of searching for multiple regular expressions and each replacing with different strings would be a bonus.

Comment: This should be migrated to SoftwareRecs.SE

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Perl.

Seriously, it makes sysadmin stuff so much easier. Here's an example:

```
perl -pi -e 's/something/somethingelse/g' *.log
```

Comment: An extension to this would be using egrep, example: `perl -pi -e 's/something/somethingelse/g'\`egrep -ril "something" ./\``

Comment: As a note, the flags are: `p`: print, for each line, `i`:edit file inline, `e`: execute command given on commandline

Comment: How to do this using `rg` and `xargs`?

Comment: Is there a way to have perl output the replaced values into a new file, with none of the non-matching data from the other file?

Answer (score 27):

`sed` is quick and easy:

```
sed -e "s/pattern/result/" <file list>
```

You can also join it with `find`:

```
find <other find args> -exec sed -e "s/pattern/result/" "{}" ";"
```

Comment: I agree on the quick.... and it is easy only for a given value of easy.  Anyways +1 ;)

Comment: Yeah, but problems begin when you have to paste 10 lines long html code with dots, slashes, quotation marks and so on to multiple files.

Comment: This doesn't appear to update the files, but simply output them. The `-i` argument appears to fix that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files

Answer (score 9):

I've written a free command line tool for Windows to do this. It's called [rxrepl](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/), it supports unicode and file search. Some may find it useful.

Answer (score 6):

[Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) does a good job of it on Windows. And it's a very good editor as well.

Comment: Couldn't agree more about TextPad being an excellent editor (my personal favourite). However, whilst it does search over multiple files (and very quickly at that) it doesn't do search and replace over multiple files.

Comment: Yes it does. What you have to do is right-click and select "Open All" in the search results. This will open all the found files. Then in the Replace dialog, click the "All Documents" radio button for where to do the replacing. After it finishes, click "Save All".

Answer (score 6):

Emacs's directory editor has the `dired-do-query-replace-regexp' function to search for and replace a regexp over a set of marked files.

Answer (score 5):

Unsurprisingly, Perl does a fine job of handling this, in conjunction with a decent shell:

```
for file in @filelist ; do
  perl -p -i -e "s/pattern/result/g" $file
done
```

This has the same effect (but is more efficient, and without the race condition) as:

```
for file in @filelist ; do
  cat $file | sed "s/pattern/result/" > /tmp/newfile
  mv /tmp/newfile $file
done
```

Comment: I also like to use "find -iname" with thatm to get a recursive search.

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows, I used to like WinGrep. This no longer appears to exist, but a new project called grepwin does. I have no experience with this, so cannot recommend it.

Under Ubuntu, I used to use [Regexxer](https://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) but found that GUIs have to work too hard to *work around* the realities of regular expressions.

These days I almost always use [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/).

Comment: WinGrep is no longer available. Now you can use [grepwin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grepwin/) instead.

Comment: **Don't edit suggestions.** WinGrep may no longer exist, but *I* have never used grepwin so please don't edit a post in my name to say I have.

Answer (score 3):

For find-and-replace on multiple files on Windows I found [rxFind](http://www.codeplex.com/RxFind) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X, TextWrangler does the job.

Comment: Especially because it provides visual feedback and allows you to review the changes it made before saving them back to files. I prefer BBEdit, its bigger brother, though, for its larger amount of functionality. Isn't free like TextWrangler, though

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite is [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) by JGSoft.  It interfaces with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) which can help you to create and test the regular expression, automatically backs up all changes (and provides undo capabilities), provides the ability to parse multiple directories (with filename patterns), and even supports file formats such as Microsoft Word, Excel, and PDF.

[image: PowerGrep Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

In Windows there is free alternative that works the best: Notepad++

Go to "Search" -> "Find in Files". One may give directory, file pattern, set regular expressions then preview the matches and finally replace all files recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I love this tool:

http://www.abareplace.com/

Gives you an "as you type" preview of your regular expression... FANTASTIC for those not well versed in RE's... and it is super fast at changing hundreds or thousands of files at a time...

And then let's you UNDO your changes as well...

Very nice...

Patrick Steil - 
http://www.podiotools.com

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for bash + find + sed.

Answer (score 1):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org)'s regex search&replace in files is pretty decent. Slightly overkill if you only use it for that, though. It also doesn't support the multi-expression-replace you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Vim for the rescue (and president ;-) ). Try:

```
vim -c "argdo! s:foo:bar:gci" <list_of_files>
```

(I do love Vim's -c switch, it's magic.
Or if you had already in Vim, and opened the files, e.g.:

```
vim <list_of_files>
```

Just issue:

```
:bufdo! s:foo:bar:gci
```

Of course `sed` and `perl` is capable as well.
HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I have the luxury of Unix and Ubuntu; In both, I use **gawk** for anything that requires line-by-line search and replace, especially for line-by-line for substring(s).
Recently, this was the fastest for processing 1100 changes against millions of lines in hundreds of files (one directory)
On Ubuntu I am a fan of regexxer

```
 sudo apt-get install regexxer
```

Answer (score 1):

if 'textpad' is a valid answer, I would suggest [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) hands down.

Multi-cursor edits are an even more efficient way to make replacements in general I find, but its "[Find in Files](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)" is top tier for bulk regex/plain find replacements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Programmer: A lot of IDEs should do a good Job as well.

For me [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/pycharm/) worked quite nice:

- *Edit > Find > Replace in Path* or **Strg + Shift + R**
- Check *Regex* at the top

It has a live preview.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the tool [RxFind](http://rxfind.codeplex.com/) useful (free OSS).

Answer (score 0):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io) (source code, deb/Ubuntu, OSx and Windows) has a good visualization of results, permitting select them individually to apply substitution. You can search by standard text, case sensitive or not, and regex.
Very important: you can exclude patterns of files and directories in the search.

Answer (score 0):

For at least 25 years, I've been using Emacs for large-scale replacements across large numbers of files.  Run `etags` to specify any set of files to search through:

```
$ etags file1.txt file2.md dir1/*.yml dir2/*.json dir3/*.md
```

Then open Emacs and run `tags-query-replace`, which prompts for regex and replacement:

```
\b\(foo\)\b
\1bar
```