# Multi line search and replace tool

Tags: search

I am looking for a tool to replace multiple lines through out a project. For example:

```
#include "../DiscreteIO/Discrete.h"
#include "../PCI/pci.h"
#include "../Arinc429/ARINC429.h"
```

with

```
#include "../PCI/pci.h"
#include "../DiscreteIO/DiscreteHW.h"
#include "../DiscreteIO/Discrete.h"
```

I have tried two tools that work for this type of search and replace. [Wildedit](http://www.textpad.com/products/wildedit/index.html) and [Actual search and replace](http://www.divlocsoft.com/) Both seem to be excellent tools but are shareware. Do anybody know of similar tools? Anything free or is it time to part with some money?

**Clarification:**

**through out a project** in this case means a thousand plus c files. The text editors can do this only one file at a time (Textpad, Programmers notepad) or in all open files(nodepad++). I haven't tried any of the other editors but I assume they will have similar problems. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Tools like sed & awk is a solution but present problems since I do not use them regularly and need to spend some time getting something to work since I am not a expert on the tools.

**The answer is:** All of it...

Ultra edit can work but I already have an editor and the price is steep if I am just going to use it as a search and replace tool.

Sed, AWK and regular expression based tools can work but can be a pain in some cases.

Wild Edit can work and is not that expensive.

My decision in the end is to work my Regular expression skills.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102083/whats-the-best-tool-to-find-and-replace-regular-expressions-over-multiple-files)

Comment: As it shows in the tutorial I linked to in my answer, UltraEdit can work with thousands of files, not open in the editor.

Comment: If you always need those files together, wouldn't it be better to create a single header that includes what is needed, in the order needed?  It would be best if the headers could be included in any order - each one should be [self-contained and idempotent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486).  And I'd recommend getting rid of the [`../`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597318) notation too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sed will do what you want.

See the FAQ entry about exactly this here http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.23.3

> If you need to match a static block of
>   text (which may occur any number of
>   times throughout a file), where the
>   contents of the block are known in
>   advance, then this script is easy to
>   use

Sed is available for Windows. See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I run the `sed -nf blockrep.sed findrep.txt` command to generate the `custom.sed` file I get the error `sed: file blockrep.sed line 18: unterminated 's' command`. Looking at the regex on that line ( `s,[/\[.*],\\&,g` ) it appears correct to me.

Comment: just edit the file and move the second `[` next to the `]` on line 18:

`s,[/\[.*],\\&,g -> s,[/\.*[],\\&,g`

the [ character inside a `[]` group must be next to the close tag ]
the ] is the opposite, must be near the open tag [ 

https://sed-users.yahoogroups.narkive.com/dKa8Aba3/replace-block-of-text#post5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280154/311834

Answer (score 12):

The JetBrains family of IDEs: [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) etc. will do a multi-line search and replace.

Select the text in question and press `ctrl-shift-F` -- this will open the replace dialog with the selected text as the find expression (using a regex with newlines escaped as `\n`)

Answer (score 4):

```
cd $PROJECTDIR && find . -iname '*.*' -exec vim -c 's:^first line of text\nsecond line of text\n3rd line of text:new 1st line\rnew 2nd\rnew 3rd:' -c 'w!' -c 'q' {} \;
```

HTH

Comment: A little explanation would be of great help.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has an exceptionally good “global” search and replace. I just used it for multiple multi-line changes on numerous files, including some Regexp search with capture and replace.

- Open VS Code
- File → Open Folder, open the folder your files reside in
- Open a file and select the text you want to replace
- CTRL + SHIFT + H to open Search & Replace
- If you selected a text it will auto-fill, even multi line. Otherwise enter the text, use SHIFT + Enter to insert newlines, and optionally enable Regexp.
- Enter the replacement text
- Press Enter to start the search
- Click on change-items to preview the changes side by side
- Use the Replace All button (CTRL + ALT + Enter) to apply and save the changes

Answer (score 3):

Only thing that works turnkey in one shot is dreamweaver....[image]

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used Multiple Find And Replace 1.10, a freeware program that do just that: searches for multiple lines in a TXT or list of TXT's and replace them with other text at your wish or delete them. I found it here for download: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Multiple-Find-And-Replace.shtml

Comment: Another obsolete answer...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment, but the accepted solution cites an example that seems broken.  Line 18 should be:

```
s,[/\.*[],\\&,g
```

Not

```
s,[/\[.*],\\&,g
```

The latter will complain with modern sed (or 'gsed' if you're in *BSD) about an unterminated expression on line 18.

Answer (score 1):

[RegexSearch](http://regexsearch.sourceforge.net/) is a bit ugly but a very useful tool for just this sort of thing.

Comment: I wasnt able to use it for recursively replacing in all files of a given type. Recursive doesnt seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I've found is a piece of freeware called [BK ReplaceEm](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/bkreplace.html). The interface takes a bit of getting used to, but it's worth learning how to use it. The tool is very powerful and allows you to do multi-line replaces with or without regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) can do that. I parted with money for it.

There is [a tutorial on multi-line find & replace](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/multiline_find_replace.html) which you can use with "[replace in files](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/find_replace.html)" to apply over multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a combination of sed, awk and/or grep would do the job. They're free and come with any Linux distribution but Windows versions exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am always perplex when people ask for tools without telling for which platform(s) they need them... In these cases, I suppose it is, by default, for Windows...

There are a number of search/replace tools available for Windows, more or less powerful, lot of them free.
Currently, I use the Search/Replace module of [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html), surprisingly powerful (you can use regular expressions), coming with lot of other goodies.
I have also RJL Soft's [Simple Search-Replace](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/search/) (no REs), TortoiseSVN author's [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/), supporting regexes and a good number of options, and there are some others I used in the past.

PS.: I forgot. Simple Search-Replace won't do multi-line replaces. Neither FileMenu Tools, apparently. grepWin can do (using \r\n for example).
I do recall such free tools with multi-line search/replace fields, but I don't have their names at hand.

Comment: Another obsolete answer... Links need to be updated. A crossplatform solution would be good

Comment: @Sharcoux Links? Only the one of FileMenu Tools leads to a 404 page, and if you go up two levels in the URL, you will find the product! I call that laziness... Cross-platform: try sed...

Comment: FileMenu Tools is obsolete. sed is far from being user friendly when it comes to multiline. Simple Search-Replace doesn't support multiline. So, maybe grepWin could answer the question. I admit that I didn't try it. If you put only grepWin to your answer, I will remove my down vote

Answer (score 0):

```
#see docs at the bottom 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

use File::Find;

my $search_patternFilePath=$ARGV[0] ;
my $replace_patternFilePath =$ARGV[1];
my $file_pattern = $ARGV[2];

# Usage

(@ARGV == 3 ) || die ("Usage: FindAndReplace.pl pathToFileContaingTheMultiLineSearchText FullPathToFileContainingMultiLineReplaceText FilePattern . Example: perl MultiLineFindAndReplace.pl \"D:\Opera\New Folder\search.txt\" \"D:\Opera\replace.txt\" bak");



find(\&d, cwd);

sub d {
my $file = $File::Find::name;
$file =~ s,/,\\,g;

return unless -f $file;
return unless $file =~ /$file_pattern/;

my $searchPatternString = &slurpFile ( $search_patternFilePath ) ; 
my $replacePatternString = &slurpFile ( $replace_patternFilePath ) ; 
my $fileStr = &slurpFile ( $file ) ; 

$fileStr =~ s/$searchPatternString/$replacePatternString/igo ; 
open(FILEHANDLE,">$file") || die "cannot open output file";
print (FILEHANDLE "$fileStr");
close FILEHANDLE ;

}

sub slurpFile 
{
my $file = shift ;
print "\$file is $file" ;
local( $/, *FILE ) ; 
open (FILE , $file) or 
die "Cannot find $file !!! " ; 
my $fileString = <FILE>; #slurp the whole file into one string !!! 
close FILE ;
return $fileString ;
}
#Purpose : performs recursive find and replace based on pеrl regexes from the current directory
#the search and replace is case insensitive
#Usage
#perl MultiLineFindAndReplace.pl "D:\Opera\New Folder\search.txt" "D:\Opera\replace.txt" bak
```