# How can I make a text file with paths to all my files of a given extension?

Tags: windows, search, file

I'm trying to use the freeware [Multiple Find And Replace 1.00](http://www.nontube.com/products/multiple-find-and-replace/) suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268045/multi-line-search-and-replace-tool#272325).

[Multiple Find And Replace 1.00 http://www.nontube.com/images/screenshot-mfar.png](http://www.nontube.com/images/screenshot-mfar.png)

Unfortunately it requires that I explicitly select each file I'd like it to search.

But, it does allow me to load in a text file of the file paths.

```
C:\one.txt  
C:\two.txt  
C:\somedirectory\three.txt
```

**I'd like a text file of paths to all files with extension .php within a certain directory and all its subdirectories (recursive).**

Does anyone know of a ready-made tool I can use to quickly generate such a list of files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use built-in DOS commands like so:

```
cd /d "[base-directory]" && dir /s /b *.php > [list file]
```

e.g.

```
cd /d "c:\my files" && dir /s /b *.php > c:\list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`dir /S /B *.php`

Answer (score 1):

If the simple:

```
dir /S /B *.php > output.txt
```

is not sufficient then [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) will certainly do the task.
The multi rename tool in Total Commander is excelent.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt, cd to the folder you want to find files in and run

```
dir *.html /B /S > somefile.txt
```

then look in somefile.txt

(looks like I lose the race .... !)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), the following one-liner will do the find-and-replace:

```
find basedir -name \*.php -exec sed -i 's/text-to-find/text-to-replace/g' '{}' '+'
```

`sed` also support regular expressions, so the text-to-find can be a regex, and the text-to-replace can contain references to groups fro the pattern text.