# Change multiple files

Tags: sed

The following command is correctly changing the contents of 2 files.

```
sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' xaa1 xab1
```

But what I need to do is to change several such files dynamically and I do not know the file names. I want to write a command that will read all the files from current directory starting with `xa*` and `sed` should change the file contents.

Comment: You mean `sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' xa*` ?

Comment: The answers here don't suffice. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files?newreg=63655f028ac04f11bbf861c7bba8db9f

Comment: Here's another answer on updating many files at once: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-all-php-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirec

Comment: I did @PaulR solution and it worked, but what I don't understand is all these complicated other answers! What is missing from your solution?

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz sometimes when there is too much files the shell will complain about the argument list length as demonstrated by the top answer

Comment: `sed` can take multiple files. All these complicated answers are just concerning the command length limit.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Better yet:

```
for i in xa*; do
    sed -i 's/asd/dfg/g' $i
done
```

because nobody knows how many files are there, and it's easy to break command line limits.

Here's what happens when there are too many files:

```
# grep -c aaa *
-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
# for i in *; do grep -c aaa $i; done
0
... (output skipped)
#
```

Comment: If there are that many files, you'll break the command line limit in the `for` command. To protect yourself from that, you'd have to use `find ... | xargs ...`

Comment: @glenn jackman: i've just tried `for i in `find .`; do echo $i; done` with 600k files, and it works, could you please elaborate, what is the limit for the `for` command and how can i break it?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong. What happens if you `echo [pattern_that_expands_to_600k_files]`?

Comment: the whole point of using `for` is to be able to **iterate** through the list of files and never have to deal with 600k files at the same time, `$i` is always a single file name. please, correct me if i'm wrong, but as far as i know, there's no limit imposed on the `for` statement.

Comment: I don't know the implementation, but the "xa*" pattern does have to get expanded at some point. Does the shell do the expansion differently for `for` than it does for `echo` or `grep`?

Comment: of course it does the expansion differently, that's why i said it's better to use `for` statement to avoid breaking command line length limitations in case of having too many files.

Comment: see the updated answer. if you need more info, please, ask an official question, so people could help you.

Comment: In the sed command, you need to use `"$i"` instead of `$i` to avoid word splitting on filenames with spaces.  Otherwise this is very nice.

Comment: Regarding the list, I believe the difference is that `for` is part of the language syntax, not even just a builtin.  For `sed -i 's/old/new' *`, the expansion of `*` must ALL be passed as an arglist to sed, and I'm fairly sure this has to happen before the `sed` process can even be started.  Using the `for` loop, the full arglist (the expansion of `*`) never gets passed as a command, only stored in the shell memory and iterated through.  I don't have any reference for this at all though, it just seems probable that is the difference.  (I'd love to hear from someone more knowledgeable...)

Answer (score 277):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the -exec argument to find, which is intended for this type of use-case, although it will start a process for each matching file name:

```
find . -type f -name 'xa*' -exec sed -i 's/asd/dsg/g' {} \;
```

Alternatively, one could use xargs, which will invoke fewer processes:

```
find . -type f -name 'xa*' | xargs sed -i 's/asd/dsg/g'
```

Or more simply use the `+` [exec variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085272/1941755) instead of `;` in find to allow find to provide more than one file per subprocess call:

```
find . -type f -name 'xa*' -exec sed -i 's/asd/dsg/g' {} +
```

Comment: I had to modify the command in this answer like so: `find ./ -type f -name 'xa*' -exec sed -i '' 's/asd/dsg/g' {} \;` that's the location for the find command `./` and a pair of single quotes after `-i` for OSX.

Comment: The find command works as it is supplied by ealfonso, `./` is equal to `.` and after `-i` has only the backupsuffix parameter.

Comment: The `-exec` option of find along with `{} +` is sufficient to solve the problem as stated, and should be fine for most requirements. But `xargs` is a better choice in general because it also allows parallel processing with the `-p` option. When your glob expansion is large enough to overflow your command line length, you are likely to also benefit from a speedup over a sequential run.

Comment: I don't know why none of these options work for me as I have used them successfully on *nix machines. I'm in terminal on a Mac though now...

Answer (score 95):

You could use grep and sed together. This allows you to search subdirectories recursively.

```
Linux: grep -r -l <old> * | xargs sed -i 's/<old>/<new>/g'
OS X: grep -r -l <old> * | xargs sed -i '' 's/<old>/<new>/g'

For grep:
    -r recursively searches subdirectories 
    -l prints file names that contain matches
For sed:
    -i extension (Note: An argument needs to be provided on OS X)
```

Comment: Bonus of this method for me was I could slip in a `grep -v` to avoid git folders `grep -rl <old> . | grep -v \.git | xargs sed -i 's/<old>/<new>/g'`

Comment: best solution for a mac!

Comment: This also works great on windows with shells like cmder, where find cannot easily be used.

Answer (score 38):

Those commands won't work in the default `sed` that comes with Mac OS X.

From `man 1 sed`:

```
-i extension
             Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified
             extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup 
             will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length
             extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption
             or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

Tried

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/old/new/g' logfile*
```

and

```
for i in logfile*; do sed -i '.bak' 's/old/new/g' $i; done
```

Both work fine.

Comment: @sumek Here's an example terminal session on OS X that shows sed replacing all occurrences: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/funroll/5504098)

Comment: I  used this to replace two different lines in all my website config files with a one-liner below.  
    sed -i.bak "s/supercache_proxy_config/proxy_includes\/supercache_config/g; s/basic_proxy_config/proxy_include\/basic_proxy_config/g" sites-available/*
Don't forget to delete the *.bak files when you are done for file system hygiene sake.

Answer (score 34):

[@PaulR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10445934/393280#comment13486175_10445934) posted this as a comment, but people should view it as an answer (and this answer works best for my needs):

```
sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' xa*
```

This will work for a moderate amount of files, probably on the order of tens, but [probably not on the order of millions](https://superuser.com/q/257250/45163).

Comment: Assume you have forward-slashes in your replacements. Another example with filepaths `sed -i 's|auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt|auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt|g' *.ovpn`.

Answer (score 15):

Another more versatile way is to use `find`:

```
sed -i 's/asd/dsg/g' $(find . -type f -name 'xa*')
```

Comment: the output of that find command gets expanded, so this doesn't address the issue. Instead you should use -exec

Comment: @erjoalgo this works because the sed command can handle multiple input files. Expansion of the find command is exactly was is needed to make it work.

Comment: it works as long as the number of files doesn't push into command line limits.

Comment: That limit is dependent only on the memory resources available to the machine and it's exactly the same as the limit for exec.

Comment: That is simply not true. In your command above, the $(find . ...) gets expanded into a single command, which could be very long if there are many matching files. If it is too long (for example in my system the limit is around 2097152 characters) you might get an error: "Argument list too long" and the command will fail. Please google this error to get some background on this.

Comment: OK, I guess I've just never expanded a search that long before.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `find` for similar task. It is quite simple: you have to pass it as an argument for `sed` like this:

`` sed -i 's/EXPRESSION/REPLACEMENT/g' `find -name "FILE.REGEX"` ``

This way you don't have to write complex loops, and it is simple to see, which files you are going to change, just run `find` before you run `sed`.

Comment: This is exactly the same as [@dkinzer’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27849922/2948889).

Answer (score 1):

u can make

'**xxxx**'  text u search and will replace it with '**yyyy**'

```
grep -Rn '**xxxx**' /path | awk -F: '{print $1}' | xargs sed -i 's/**xxxx**/**yyyy**/'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some good answers above. I thought I'd throw in one more that is succinct and parallelizable, using GNU parallel, which I often prefer to `xargs`:

```sh
parallel sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' {} ::: xa*
```

Combine this with the `-j N` option to run `N` jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

## The Silver Searcher Solution

I'm adding another option for those people who don't know about the amazing tool called [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (command line tool is **ag**).

*Note: You can use grep and other tools to do the same thing here, but The Silver Searcher is fantastic :)*

### TLDR

```bash
ag -l 'abc' | xargs sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

### Install The Silver Searcher

```bash
sudo apt install silversearcher-ag                # Debian / Ubuntu
sudo pacman -S the_silver_searcher                # Arch / EndeavourOS
sudo yum install epel-release the_silver_searcher # RHEL / CentOS
```

### Demo Files

Paste the following into your terminal to create some demonstration files:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/food
cd /tmp/food
content="Everybody loves to abc this food!"
echo "$content" > ./milk
echo "$content" > ./bread
mkdir ./fastfood
echo "$content" > ./fastfood/pizza
echo "$content" > ./fastfood/burger
mkdir ./fruit
echo "$content" > ./fruit/apple
echo "$content" > ./fruit/apricot
```

### Using 'ag'

The following **ag** command will recursively find all the files that contain the string 'abc'. It ignores the .git directory, .gitignore files, and other ignore files:

```bash
$ ag 'abc'
milk
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!

bread
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!

fastfood/burger
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!

fastfood/pizza
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!

fruit/apple
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!

fruit/apricot
1:Everybody loves to abc this food!
```

To just list the files that contain the string 'abc', use the `-l` switch:

```bash
$ ag -l 'abc'
bread
fastfood/burger
fastfood/pizza
fruit/apricot
milk
fruit/apple
```

### Changing Multiple Files

Finally, using xargs and sed, we can replace the 'abc' string with another string:

```bash
ag -l 'abc' | xargs sed -i 's/abc/eat/g'
```

In the above command, `ag` is listing all the files that contain the string 'abc'. The `xargs` command is splitting the file names and piping them individually into the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run a script, here is what I did for a similar situation:

Using a dictionary/hashMap (associative array) and variables for the `sed` command, we can loop through the array to replace several strings. Including a wildcard in the `name_pattern` will allow to replace in-place in files with a pattern (this could be something like `name_pattern='File*.txt'` ) in a specific directory (`source_dir`).
All the changes are written in the `logfile` in the `destin_dir`

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir=source_path
destin_dir=destin_path
logfile='sedOutput.txt'
name_pattern='File.txt'

echo "--Begin $(date)--" | tee -a $destin_dir/$logfile
echo "Source_DIR=$source_dir destin_DIR=$destin_dir "

declare -A pairs=( 
    ['WHAT1']='FOR1'
    ['OTHER_string_to replace']='string replaced'
)

for i in "${!pairs[@]}"; do
    j=${pairs[$i]}
    echo "[$i]=$j"
    replace_what=$i
    replace_for=$j
    echo " "
    echo "Replace: $replace_what for: $replace_for"
    find $source_dir -name $name_pattern | xargs sed -i "s/$replace_what/$replace_for/g" 
    find $source_dir -name $name_pattern | xargs -I{} grep -n "$replace_for" {} /dev/null | tee -a $destin_dir/$logfile
done

echo " "
echo "----End $(date)---" | tee -a $destin_dir/$logfile
```

First, the pairs array is declared, each pair is a replacement string, then `WHAT1` will be replaced for `FOR1` and `OTHER_string_to replace` will be replaced for `string replaced` in the file `File.txt`. In the loop the array is read, the first member of the pair is retrieved as `replace_what=$i` and the second as `replace_for=$j`. The `find` command searches in the directory the filename (that may contain a wildcard) and the `sed -i` command replaces in the same file(s) what was previously defined. Finally I added a `grep` redirected to the logfile to log the changes made in the file(s).

This worked for me in `GNU Bash 4.3` `sed 4.2.2` and based upon VasyaNovikov's answer for  [Loop over tuples in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713104/loop-over-tuples-in-bash).