# Rename multiple files with sed

Tags: linux, sed, rename

How can i rename files with titles like `Stargate SG-1 Season 01 Episode 01` to just "s01e01"? Variable numbering of course.
I already have something like this:

> `for file in *.mkv; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e "REGEX HERE")`

I just need the sed command that does what i need.

Thanks

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files

Comment: @user1929959, that question is about changing content of multiple files, this question asks about renaming multiple files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for sed, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mkv;
do
    set -- $f
    mv "$f" s${4}e${6}
done
```

in action:

```
$ ls
Stargate SG-1 Season 01 Episode 01.mkv

$ ./l.sh 

$ ls
s01e01.mkv
```

Comment: He asked for `sed`. How do you know that he doesn't need `sed`? This example may be only a single case, and he may have a lot of others with will need `sed`. Also, your answer is dependent on `bash` and he may be using another shell.

Comment: well, OP accepted the answer so I guess it solved the issues. If you think you have a better solution, post it and see what happens :-)

Comment: Being the OP doesn't make him the final arbiter of the truth, and an answer being accepted does not mean it was good, in fact it doesn't mean it was even an answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### GNU sed

```
for file in *.mkv; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/.*\(\S\+\)\s\+\S\+\s\(\S\+\)$/s\1e\2/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk is also good for this

```
for file in *.mkv; do
   mv "$file" $(awk '{print "s", $4, "e", $6}' <<<$file).mkv
done
```

I think that this is not a problem for sed :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way to rename all *.mkv files:

`ls *.mkv | awk '{print "mv \"" $0 "\" s" $4 "e" $6}' | sh`

or

`ls *.mkv | awk '{print "\"" $0 "\" s" $4 "e" $6}' | xargs mv`