# CSV manipulation with sed - apply sed to multiple lines

Tags: csv, sed

I know this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files) but I haven't quite figured it out (command line noob).  So, here is a sed command that deletes the first seven lines of a csv and then the last two lines.

```
cat test.csv | sed "1,7d" | sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d' > test2.csv
```

Now, based on some other posts, I have been putting together something that will allow me to apply this script to all my csv files in a single folder.  I have been piecing together lots of different code examples but it seems I have to have a single sed command rather than piping them together.  Any assistance to help a noob would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about `sed -e "1,7d" -e 'N;$!P;$!D;$d'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"delete first 7 lines and then the last 2 for all files in a directory"

```
for file in *.csv; do 
    sed '1,7d' "$file" | tac | sed '1,2d' | tac > "$file.new"
done
```