# Adding words (tags) to a file

Tags: bash, echo

I want to add the words "Getting started" to two markdown files (so the extension is .md). They are named:
* installing-disqus.md
* installing-google-analytics.md

I would like to populate that word right after the line "Tags: " so the outcome would be "Tags: Getting started"

In Bash, what command would I write. I am thinking it would look something like this:

```
echo "Getting started" >> *installing* *Tags:*
```

Comment: Hint: try using `sed`.

Comment: How is this related to keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to do a find and replace. Since you want the words added after Tags: (assumming there is only one such line) you could run:

`sed -i “s/Tags:/Tags:<your text here>/g” <filename>`

-i means that it will do the changes in the file
s/ means it will do a substitution
/
/g do this substitution in the whole file

Comment: This is headed in the right direction. How would I do it with two files Andrei? Both files start with "installing" and and in ".md" - "installing-disqus.md" and "installing-google-analytics.md"

Comment: You can use the wildcard operator “*” but better yet read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10446276/10632970 .

Comment: I am not sure what to do about the error message I got. Here is my attempt: sed -i "s/Tags:/Tags: Getting started/g" *installing*

Comment: Here is my error: sed: 1: "installing-disqus.md": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: Can you tell me what environment your are using? I tried this command on Ubuntu 18.10 and it worked.

Comment: I am on a Mac, using bash.

Comment: Macs use a different version of sed, replace the -i with -e. You can read more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/10632970