# Sed * only modifying first file

Tags: sed, macos-high-sierra

I would like to delete the first 40 lines of a good number of ASCII files and save the ASCII files without those 40 lines

I'm working under OSX High Sierra, realized that the `-i` option in `sed` was not working unless I create a backup file, so I tried using this command:

```
sed -i'backup' -e '1,40d' *.txt
```

It however only modifies and deletes the first 40 lines in my first file (alphabetically), but not the others.

How can I edit multiple files with just one command?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files)

Comment: Won't work on OSX Sierra. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command that will

- look in the current folder
- ignore sub folder
- take only into account files whose filenames end with '*.txt'
- before executing the `sed` command.

**Command:**

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 'backup' -e '1,40d' {} \;
```