# How to find a line and replace with two lines with same indent in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, replace

I want to insert another line after each occurrence of a searched line. Like, I have 50+ JSON files with lines like:

```sh
(\s)+Line1\n
```

I want to replace it with same indentation like:

```sh
(\s)+Line1\n
(\s)+Line2\n
```

How to do it in Intellij community version?(2019.2)

Comment: Maybe you should try some command line tools like `sed`. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace in path (under edit->find). The replace string can span multiple lines. Press ctrl-shift-enter to enter a new line in the replacement string text box. However the new string will be a fixed string and won't necessarily have the same indent as the original string. For this you will have to auto format the files.

Comment: Actuall at last I end with something like you said: replace without format and then select the folder and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F</kbd> to auto-format. Thanks for the tip of new line in replace box.