# Tool for refactoring types in C code

Tags: c, types, refactoring, stdint

I'm looking for a tool which can refactor types (!) in C code.

I have a complex and relatively big codebase where we decided to switch from built-in integral types to types with explicit width. Like changing every instances of "*unsigned int*" to "*uint32_t*" and similar.

I know that there are many tools for refactoring for example names but none of them which I know can **fully** refactor types. For example, Visual Assist might be able to refactor "long" as a single token but cannot refactor "unsigned long".

Comment: Search and replace? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102083/whats-the-best-tool-to-find-and-replace-regular-expressions-over-multiple-files

Comment: Do you have to worry about the aconventional but valid `int unsigned` too?

Comment: Do want a string-hacking solution, or a tool that really understands the C language?  The former is workable (with you cleaning up the mess) for smallish code bases.   The latter is need (IMHO) if you have a large code base and don't want have to make lots of fixes to a string-hacking result.

Comment: Textual approach: easy and tempting, but as Ira said it will be messy and I have been trying to find a clean solution

Comment: C language based solution: it would be preferable. The point is (as  I wrote before) that some refactoring tools can replace types with one token but not two. So I would like to have a tool which explicitly supports this.